# jquery table filtering/sorting plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hey guys,
Are there any table sorting plugins that let you 'opt out' from sorting once you have sorted a column, restoring the the table to the unsorted/default state as when the table was loaded? And also gives hints on the order of columns clicked when multiple columns are used for sorting?

Answer (score 0):

What about [jQuery tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin?

Have a look at its demo [here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo)